# How do I get an image to appear behind the header?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am currently working in HTML and CSS. I need to make an image the background of the header.

```css
#banner {
  padding: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/800x300");
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <h1>AlexArgent</h1>
  <p>My Personal Homepage</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You've modified the demo so that it works and my answer is moot. Please also revise your question to explain the problem more clearly. See [ask].

Comment: It might help if you defined "header" for us. Are you referring to the banner element, or to the head*ing* element? A header is usually a container at the top of a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `background` shorthand property overrides the `background-image` property. Use `background-color` instead of the former, or include the color value in it.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background.

```css
#banner {
  padding: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1abc9c url("https://via.placeholder.com/300x100");
  /* or this:
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300x100");
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  */
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /* for demo only */
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <h1>AlexArgent</h1>
  <p>My Personal Homepage</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.header {
  padding: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
  
  background-color: #1abc9c;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/300x100");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>AlexArgent</h1>
  <p>My Personal Homepage</p>
</div>
```

I would suggest to use "header" some where in code example so those who answer can understand where exactly you want to use picture as background, also highly recommended not use id as a selector, this is bad practice you can find out yourself why, also just as @isherwod i suggest drop using background property, use for each property it is own - background-color, background-img etc. Use such properties as background-position and background-size - they will help you to adjust your picture. the code from @isherwood works - you might missing something in your project